# How to print the subject of a single email using uid

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, imap

I'm looking to print the subject of a single email whose UID I already have using the python 2.7 imap libraries. It's pretty simple, I'm new to Python and am just having trouble using the library.

Here's what I have:

```
# Retrieve and store ID & UID for most recent email received

result, data = mail.search(None,'ALL') # search and return sequential ids
latest_id = data[0].split()[-1]

result, data = mail.uid('search', None, "ALL") # search and return uids instead
latest_uid = data[0].split()[-1]
```

Now I'm just looking to print the subject of the email identified by `latest_uid`.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would approach getting the subject is to fetch the entire message data using RFC 822 (email message standard format), and then convert it into a python email object using the email module.

Using RFC 822 will fetch the entire message, but if you only need the subject you can just fetch the header (commented out below). If you decide to only fetch for the header, just parse for the line that begins with `Subject:`.

The imaplib documentation https://pymotw.com/2/imaplib/ has a more in depth of what's happening in the code below.

```
import email, imaplib

# typ, msg_data = c.fetch('1', '(BODY.PEEK[HEADER])') 
t, d = mail.fetch(latest_uid, '(RFC822)')


for res_part in d:
    if isinstance(res_part, tuple):
    msg = email.message_from_string(res_part[1])
    subject = msg['subject']
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfectly. Thanks!